# ZF2 Routing configuration via RouteProviderInterface

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have been trying to configure our `Module.php` to use [the Module Manager Listeners](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.module-manager.module-manager.html#zend-module-manager-module-manager-module-manager-listeners) for configuration (i.e interfaces that are available under `Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\*`). Specifically, I want to be able to configure the routes of my module *outside* of the main `module.config.php`. I  have not been able to find any actual examples of this.

What I have found, if I have read the documentation correctly, is that the method `getRouteConfig()` should merge in my routes into the array provided by `getConfig()`?

**Module.php**

```
class Module implements Feature\RouteProviderInterface
{
//...
  public function getRouteConfig()
  {
    return include __DIR__ . '/config/route.config.php';
  }
  //...
}
```

**/config/route.config.php**

```
return array(

  'route_manager' => array(
    'router' => array (
      'routes' => array(
         //.. routes that were working correctly when added to module.config.php
      ),
     ),
   ),
 );
```

I can see the array returned via `getRouteConfig()` so I know the method is being called correctly.

Perhaps I am misunderstanding the purpose of the above interface, or I have not provided the correct "key" (`route_manager`) for this to be merged correctly, as I'm getting 404 for my routes.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I have it working but I only use the `getConfig()`. What is do is I use an `array_merge` in the `getConfig()`.

```
public function getConfig()
{
    return array_merge(
        require_once 'path_to_config/module.config.php',
        require_once 'path_to_config/routes.config.php'
    );
}
```

My `router.config.php` looks then like:

```
return [
    'router' => [
        'routes' => [
            // routes
        ]
    ]
];
```

This way I also got some other config files seperated (ACL).

Edit
Thanks to the article [Understanding ZF2-Configuration](http://samminds.com/2013/04/understanding-zf2-configuration/), I got an idea. I think your array should **not be**:

```
return array(
    'route_manager' => array(
        'router' => array (
            'routes' => array(
                //.. routes that were working correctly when added to module.config.php
            )
        )
    )
);
```

but **rather be**

```
return array(
    'router' => array (
        'routes' => array(
            //.. routes that were working correctly when added to module.config.php
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the input @Hendriq, I had thought this would work, although I've not tried it. I guess I will have to implement it this way  unless anyone else can shed some light on the correct use of the interface.

Comment: Did some research about the topic, and well did not found much either. But found an intresting article, so I updated my answer with some more stuff

Comment: +1 for reading up on a topic that you don't have perfect knowledge of just to help someone else ;) Slightly edited your formatting tho :P

Comment: +1 @Hendriq, I've accepted your answer as you provided a working solution to the problem (using `array_merge` in `getConfig()`) However, thanks to you both.

Comment: The fact is getRouteConfig goal is NOT to return routes config (which is used by the router), BUT route plugins (which is used by RoutePluginManager). For example, if you implement a dynamic routing, you will probably create a router plugin that you will declare under `router_manager.[invokables|factories|abstract_factories]` key.
Unfortunaley, there is very few documentation about this. But, you can find something in [Router doc](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html#zend-mvc-router-http-part)

Answer (score 3):

I haven't done this in the way you mentioned yet, but the key `route_manager` is not required within the `getRouteConfig()` Method.

This is due to the fact that all of the `get{$specificManager}Config()`-Methods are called directly from their respective Manager-Classes. Therefore the initial key is not required. Using another terminology, when using `getRouteConfig()` you are already in the scope of `route_manager`. Same as when you use `getServiceConfig()` you're already in the scope of `service_manager`. However `getConfig()` is within the application-scope and therefore accessing configuration of application-parts, you need to address tose specificaly.

One thing to note is: the configuration of `getConfig()` can be cached to increase performance, whereas all the other `get{$specificManager}Config()` methods are not. Especially in the case of the RouteConfiguration I'd highly suggest to use the `getConfig()`-Method for your RouteConfig.

If you really need to separate the configuration, then I'd suggest the way that @Hendriq displayed for you.

Comment: Thanks Sam. Makes sense regarding the configuration key and it's an interesting point regarding the caching - I had thought that the final *merged* config would be cached, rather than just the result of `getConfig`?

Comment: Lol, found your article about this subject. Before any of the docs

Comment: @AlexP The point of the `get{$sm}Config()`-Methods is to allow for the implementation of `\Closure` inside Configuration. As those can not be serialized there is no way for them to be cached. For this reason those methods will be merged after the initial configuration has already been cached. This - i hope - should be pointed out in my article which Hendriq linked.

Comment: +1 for "Methods is to allow for the implementation of \Closure inside Configuration" Having now looked into the code - it seems that the interface is designed to bootstrap the the `RoutePluginManager` (not the configuration of the routes!) so the method `getRouteConfig` should be using the same array structure as the one returned from `getServiceConfig()` and the routes always defined in the `getConfig` method (or at least merged in as @Hendriq mentioned)

Answer (score 2):

The `getRouteConfig` is similar to the other providers it is there so you're able to create some custom routes. I guess what you're trying to do is most appropiate through hendriq's method.

An example of `getRouteConfig`can be found at http://zf2cheatsheet.com/

```
public function getRouteConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'pageRoute' => function ($routePluginManager) {
                $locator = $routePluginManager->getServiceLocator();
                $params = array('defaults' => array('controller' => 'routeTest','action' => 'page','id' => 'pages'));
                $route = Route\PageRoute::factory($params);
                $route->setServiceManager($locator);
                return $route;
            },
        ),
    );
}
```

In our `Module\Route` namespace we create the class `PageRoute` which implements `Zend\Mvc\Http\RouteInterface` and, in our specific case for the example, `Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManagerAwareInterface`. Now just implement the functions of the interface... In the sample he uses Doctrine to load the pages from the database.

Finally we can add our new custom route to our `module.config.php` so it can be used:

```
'page' => array(
    'type' => 'pageRoute',
),
```

As you can see in this last step we go back to Hendriq's solution as the intended use is not to load the routes into the router, but creating custom routes.

Hope this helps

Comment: Juan, your absolutely right, I had eventually worked it out! +1 for the the example and *great* link!